# Outlook web addin - Addin displayed randomally

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook web addin and we are experiencing some issues.

1/ The addin is sometimes not visible from the Outlook web client for generic mailboxes (the user's email address was added in the addin deployment).

2/ Same for the Outlook desktop client.

3/ Sometimes it is the first person connected of the day who connects to the generic mailbox who will determine if the addin will be visible. Let me explain, if a person has the rights to see the addin on their personal mailbox and they connect first, then all users with access to the generic mailbox will see the addin, even if they do not have the addin on their personal mailbox. On the other hand, if she does not have access to the addin from her personal box, no one will see the addin even if they have rights to the addin from their personal box.

So, how to determine that the addin is visible from the desktop client and the web client, for a person whose personal email address is present in the list of email addresses for which the addin is deployed, regardless of which mailbox it is on found (personal or generic). And conversely, if a user is not present in the list, he will not see the addin, regardless of which mailbox he is in.

I hope to have been clear

Comment: Quite a lot of common information from which it is not clear what exactly you are doing. I'd suggest being more specific in your statements and post issues to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) where MS employees can help with different kind of problems.

Comment: Are all these accounts listed as main/primary accounts in Outlook? Does your add-in support shared folders?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and as asked, does your addin has SupportSharedFolders true in manifest and by generic mailbox do you mean shared mailbox?